# MudDialog - how to execute default action button on return key press?

Tags: blazor, mudblazor

Considering this dialog below, how do I:

- make `Create` button default (or submit) button?
- enable `MudTextField` to submit on return (enter) key press?

Adding `ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit"` doesn't seem to change anything.

```
<MudDialog IsVisible="true" Class="pa-4" >
    <DialogContent>
        <MudTextField @bind-Value="NewName" Label="Name" Variant="Variant.Outlined" />
    </DialogContent>
    <DialogActions>
        <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" OnClick="CloseCreateNewNameDialog">Cancel</MudButton>
        <MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="CreateNewName">Create</MudButton>
    </DialogActions>
</MudDialog>
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am not very used to MudBlazor, but I don't see any forms. Why changing the button type to submit would change anything in your case? However, in Blazor, you have an event named @onkeyup using KeyboardEventArgs: check the Code to know if it is the Enter button that has been pushed.

Comment: I was hoping MudDialog is a form of its own therefore looking for MudBlazor specific solution. Maybe there is sth built in

Comment: MudDialog seems to be a dialog: a window showing/asking for information from user. If you are looking for a form: [MudForm](https://mudblazor.com/components/form#simple-form-validation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the create button submit you have to use the Form tag from MudBlazor :
https://mudblazor.com/components/form#simple-form-validation

```html
<MudButton Variant="Variant.Filled" ButtonType="ButtonType.Submit" Color="Color.Primary" OnClick="CreateNewName">Create</MudButton>
```

and to enable MudTextField to submit on return on keypress, use the EventCallBacks OnKeyPress

Comment: Around the entire dialog?

Comment: No, inside MudDialog